# How to get .push key from a child key - value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to get the .push key when in a child containing a specific key value.

Another words, I want to get the parent key when a specific value in a child is used.

My objective is so when a users selects a particular item on a list I can go backwards get the key of that list name and then get the parent, in this case being the .push key.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Nay.png[1]

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: I have tried multiple things, tried to use new ValueListener and loop through each of the keys but then got stuck to then get the key back depending on the item which the user selected from the key value pair. I did think to use the HashMap with a shopping list POJO. However, I dont particuallry like that way as i am reading all the data (push keys) in the datashot

Answer (score 1):

However you achieve retrieving the list item reference, call get `getParent()` to move up the tree and `getKey()` to get that parents name/id/key

```
<some-reference-to-list-item>.getParent().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get user value
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            // ...
        }
});
```

References:

[Firebase Android Retrieve Data 3.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#sort_data)

[Firebase Android Database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/package-summary#interfaces)

Comment: The problem is that the way I wrote the the code i am struggling to get the get the parent please look at my code see what you think:

https://github.com/danmaia1992/Family_Shop_Share.git